# Merge and display data from different table with PHP

Tags: php, sql, merge

I'm editing a program in PHP and I want to display a table with data from different table.
Now I have 2 tables and I am only printing the first table (registro_eu) with this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM registro_eu WHERE MONTH(data_conv) = 7 AND YEAR(data_conv) = 2016";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo '<div class="table-responsive">';
    echo '<table class="table table-striped">';
    echo '<thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Date</th>
                      <th>Desc</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>';

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td>'. $row["data"].'</td>
                        <td>'. $row["desc"].'</td>
                    </tr>';
    }

    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
    echo '</div>';

}
```

TABLE REGISTRO_EU:

```
ID | DATE       | DESC
-----------------------------
1  | 2016-06-15 | TEST DESCT
2  | 2016-06-15 | TEST 2
3  | 2016-06-15 | TEST 3
4  | 2016-06-16 | TEST DESCT
5  | 2016-06-16 | TEST 4
6  | 2016-06-17 | TEST 5
```

TABLE FONDI:

```
ID | DATE       | TOT
-----------------------------
1  | 2016-06-15 | 88
2  | 2016-06-16 | 100
3  | 2016-06-17 | 120
```

And I want to display to user (with php) something like this:

```
DATE       | DESC        |TOT
-------------------------------
2016-06-15 | TEST DESCT  |
2016-06-15 | TEST 2      |
2016-06-15 | TEST 3      |88
2016-06-16 | TEST DESCT  |
2016-06-16 | TEST 4      |100
2016-06-17 | TEST 4      |120
```

Comment: Looks like it will be easier if you JOIN these two tables.

Comment: Why aren't you fetching the joined data via sql?

Comment: Furthermore, please look into separation of concerns. This is the kind of code that will come back to haunt you.

Comment: ok, I will try with a join....thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use joins:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM registro_eu LEFT JOIN fondi ON registro_eu.DATE = fondi.DATE WHERE MONTH(data_conv) = 7 AND YEAR(data_conv) = 2016";
```

you will have to disambiguate which table you're talking about in the WHERE clause but I don't know your schema so I'll leave that to you.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)